# How can I handle the failure of a DELETE statement to delete any rows?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-delete

I wrote this code to delete a row from a table – but if I enter a name which is not in the table, it still outputs "Data Deleted Successfully":

```
n = input("Enter Student name you want to delete:")
try:
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM studentdata WHERE name=?', (n,))
    print("Data Deleted Successfully")
    conn.commit()
except:
    print("No data found with this name: ")
```

How can I handle this properly?

Comment: Deleting 0 rows is not an error like you seem to think.

Comment: You may find the [rowcount attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) of the cursor class of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cursor.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) will only raise an exception if the SQL statement it attempts to execute fails – for example:

```
>>> cur.execute("This is not SQL")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "This": syntax error
```

or

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM nonexistent_table;")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: nonexistent_table
```

A valid SQL statement which correctly does nothing has succeeded, not failed, and so doesn't raise an exception. Your `DELETE` statement is correct to do nothing when it doesn't find the provided value for `name`, so there's no error.

You can find out how many rows were affected by an SQL statement using the [`Cursor.rowcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) attribute. Rewriting your code to make use of the attribute would look something like this:

```
name = input("Enter Student name you want to delete:")
cur.execute('DELETE FROM studentdata WHERE name = ?;', [name])
if cur.rowcount > 0:
    print("Data Deleted Successfully")
    conn.commit()
else:
    print("No data found with this name:", name)
```

Note: I've left the `commit()` where it was in your code … depending on your application, it may be that it should in fact be moved outside the `if`/`else` block.